# How does Promise.completeWith differ from Promise.tryCompleteWith?

Tags: scala

`scala.concurrent.Promise`

I tried to find out the difference between `completeWith` and `tryCompleteWith` in scaladoc but there is not much explanation and no examples.
Also I'm afraid reading the source code with my current level of expertize could mislead me. Need your advice guys with some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.completeWith` is just a wrapper which calls `Promise.tryCompleteWith`:

```
/** Completes this promise with the specified future, once that future is completed.
 *
 *  @return   This promise
 */
final def completeWith(other: Future[T]): this.type = tryCompleteWith(other)

/** Attempts to complete this promise with the specified future, once that future is completed.
 *
 *  @return   This promise
 */
final def tryCompleteWith(other: Future[T]): this.type = {
    other onComplete { this tryComplete _ }
    this
}
```

To be honest I don't know why they made that decision as it looks like a simple wrapper, nothing more.

### Edit

As @Alexey Romanov points out, [this GitHub issue points out the reason for this](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4215) deprecation:

> Calling `completeWith` when the `DefaultPromise` is already completed,
>   leads to callbacks not being properly executed.
>
> This happened because `Future.InternalCallbackExecutor` extends
>   `BatchingExecutor` which assumes `unbatchedExecute` to be async,
>   when in this case it is sync, and if there is an exception thrown
>   by executing the batch, it creates a new batch with the remaining
>   items from the current batch and submits that to `unbatchedExecute`
>   and then rethrows, but if you have a sync `unbatchedExecute`, it will
>   fail since it is not reentrant, as witnessed by the failed `require`
>   as reported in this issue.
>
> This commit avoids problem by delegating `completeWith` to `tryComplete`,
>   which has the effect of using `onComplete` + `tryComplete` i.s.o. `complete`,
>   which means that when it fails (because of a benign race condition between
>   completers) it won't throw an exception.

Comment: doesnt this makes completeWith a redundant function which is not required?

Comment: @rogue-one Not sure what was the rational behind that decision.

Comment: ok, so there is no semantic difference as it might be concluded from the `Completes this promise` and `Attempts to complete this promise` descriptions in the scaladoc. Thanks.

Comment: To me the method names would sound as if one throws an exception and the other ignores the error case, but that's apparently not what happens.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4215 explains it. It wasn't redundant originally, now it is redundant and deprecated in Scala 2.12.